# How to prevent div with absolute position from leaving out the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know CSS and HTML as i know i can't do that with only these two.

```
<div class="hidden">
   <img class="mini-icon" src="media/images/runes.png" height="25" width="35" alt="">
   <!-- The DIV THAT LOOKS LIKE A TOOLTIP -->
   <div class="hidden-runes">
      Content
   </div>
</div>
```

I think the logic could be this way:

► Javascript get the current page height (ex.: 1500px) and stores it in a variable (page-height)

► Javascript detect if the hidden-runes class has changed his diplay value (ex.: `display: none` -- Hovering -turns into- `display: block`)

► Once the `display` is now `block`, javascript check the current page height again and compares with the stored value (ex.: `new-page-height - page-height = x`)

► if the `x` value is greater than 0 (ex.: `x = 100px`) then javascript gets `.hidden-runes` `top` value and substract by the `x` value

I'm sorry for any misunderstood. If any of you could indicate me a book or site (or any other way) to learn javascript fast i would be so grateful

Comment: this could be a start: http://api.jquery.com/height/ combining with http://api.jquery.com/css/ to get the display value. also good to learn is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript and everytihng from http://api.jquery.com (the speed on learning depends on you)

Comment: you don't need necessarily javascript

Comment: @SuperHornet how do you think i could do this without js?

Comment: you can handle that with css like `position:absolute` ,`left or right=xx px`,` top or bottom= xx px` and nothing changed by resizing window